# Breakout game - Collision detection

Tags: c++, windows-8

I'm writing a Breakout game in C++ with DirectXTK libraries for Windows 8 and I'm having a bit of a trouble with collision detection between the Ball and Brick objects which are inside a vector. Ball class is responsible for collision detection with the paddle and the bricks. It has an Update method which has references to Paddle object and Brick object in it's declaration. Now the collision with the paddle works just fine as Paddle is declared in the main Game class but I don't know how to refer to an object(s) which are stored in a vector. By the way if I remove "Brick& brick" from Ball::Update method declaration, 5 rows of bricks are drawn as intended.

Ball update class

```
void Ball::Update(float timeDelta, Rect windowBounds, Paddle& paddle, Brick& brick)
{

//Respond to collision with the Paddle
if ( paddle.IntersectsWith(this->boundingBox))
{
    this->velocity.y = this->velocity.y * -1;
}

// Respond to collision with the brick
if (brick.IntersectsWith(this->boundingBox))
{
    this->velocity.y = this->velocity.y * -1;
    brick.Hit();
    this->score+= 10;
}
}
```

This is how Brick objects are initialized in the Game class, bricksRow is the vector

```
//Next, create this many Brick objects and store them in a std::vector
for (int j = 0; j < bricksNumberOfRows; j+=32)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfBricks ; i++)
    {
        //Add a Brick object to the back of the vector
        this->bricksRow.push_back(Brick());
        //Get a local reference to this newly added Brick object
        Brick& brick = this->bricksRow.back();
        //Call the initialise method on the newly added Brick object
        brick.Initialize(L"Assets/Brick.png"
            , this->d3dDevice
            , this->d3dDeviceContext
            , Vector2((float)(i * this->brickWidth), bricksStartingPosition + j));
    }
}
```

And here the ball.Update method gets called in the Game class

```
 this->ball.Update(timeDelta, this->windowBounds, this->paddle, ******* );
```

Where the stars are, I should refer to a Brick& objects in a vector but I don't know how to.

Thank you for the replies in advance.

Comment: What you want is a reference to to a vector that stores Bricks: `void Ball::Update(..., (std::vector<Brick>)& bricks)`

Comment: This way I can't call methods from Brick class in Ball class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to detect collision of the paddle against each of the brick object in the vector, so you can enumerate and call *Update()* like this:

```
vector<Brick>::iterator ci;
for(ci = bricksRow.begin(); ci! = bricksRow.end(); ci++)
{
    this->ball.Update(timeDelta, this->windowBounds, this->paddle, *ci);
}
```

If you know the index of the brick object for which you want to detect collision (let's say it's stored in the variable *index*), you can call as follow:

```
this->ball.Update(timeDelta, this->windowBounds, this->paddle, bricksRow[index]);
```

**Update**: The iterator should be iterator instead of const_iterator, so instead of

```
vector<Brick>::const_iterator ci;
```

it should be

```
vector<Brick>::iterator ci;
```

Better yet, since you are not modifying the object *brick* inside **void Ball::Update(float timeDelta, Rect windowBounds, Paddle& paddle, Brick& brick)**, if you could change it to
**void Ball::Update(float timeDelta, Rect windowBounds, Paddle& paddle, const Brick& brick)**, then you can keep

```
vector<Brick>::const_iterator ci;
```

The explanation of the difference probably deserves a separate question.  The above probably should help you getting around the problem you're currently having.

Comment: I want to detect collision of the ball against each of the brick object in the vector, I think that's what you meant in your answer. Anyways I get an error in this line where *ci is 

     this->ball.Update(timeDelta, this->windowBounds, this->paddle,      *ci); 

It says Error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "Brick &" to initialize of type "const Brick"

Comment: With the iterator the ball.Update gets called enormous amount of times and the ball updates many times a second. I believe it updates every time iterator iterates through the vector which is all the time. And thank you for your time Kevin.